# "Press any key to boot from USB" doesn't work on Windows 10 install

Tags: windows-10, windows-installation

[Please do not vote to close! Most of the solutions I've found involve a PS/2 Keyboard; or one of the things I have tried]

A little information: I am running Ubuntu 16.04, and was running Windows 7 alongside it on a different HDD, but wiped my Windows 7 drive in preparation for Windows 10.

I am trying to install Windows 10 alongside my Ubuntu 16.04 installation. In preparation for this I backed up important files and wiped the HDD containing Windows 7. Now I'm trying to install Windows 10, it fails at "Press any key to boot from USB". For some reason my keyboard works in the BIOS, doesn't work during boot, and then comes back again at the Ubuntu logo (or did start working at the Windows login screen, before I wiped it).

My keyboard has never worked before in GRUB, nor when Windows has an error and hits the black "Recovery" screen; GRUB and recovery just time out to the first option, no matter what I do. Though this has not been a problem as the OSes are on different drives, so I can just change the boot option in the BIOS.

Things I've tried:

- Enabling/Disabling legacy USB support in BIOS
- Removing `bootfix` file from USB (supposedly removes the "press any.." message and continues automatically - doesn't)
- Plugging keyboard into new USB port, restarting into USB, mashing keyboard, trying again for all 10 ports
- A different USB keyboard, again in all 10 ports
- Disabling all other boot options in BIOS (creates a loop of the "Press any.." screen)

I've read that this problem can be alleviated by using a PS/2 keyboard, but I don't have one or know anybody that does; and would rather not order one and wait for it, just to use it to press one button.

**Actual question:** how can I boot into a Windows 10 USB installer without "Press any key..." prompt before boot, or how can I remove this prompt from the USB drive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a <s>solution</s> workaround, I had to reinstall Windows 7 so that I could use the `setup.exe` file to install Windows 10 from inside Windows 7. I was met with an error stating that my install disk was not 64 bit, so I used the `setup.exe` file in the sources folder, which apparently supported 64 bit. This is unhelpful if you are using an OEM copy of Windows 10.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

Use Rufus ... Under Advanced ... The Arrow Next to Format Options...
Checkmark Use Rufus To Write MBR Bios ID
Use Macrium Reflect.iso as a bootable.iso

I also like to see a Progress Bar... You want the Text On The Left
so it's out of the way from the Windows 10 Wait Logo that will show up.

I modified the "Windows is loading files" in the Center... to... Loading Files... From The Far Left.
I changed the padding from 25 to 2 using a Text Editor and Resource Editor.

Modified the BootMgr.exe.mui type file... same as BootMgr.exe.efi.mui
The BootMgr.exe.mui file is an example of Windows is Loading Files
with the Progress Bar... I add the Progress Bar on all my USB Flash
Drives so I can see how long it will take before it loads...
Like I said I modified the 23 BOOTMGR.XSL Resource exported the txt file
and modified it and added the Resource back to 23 BOOTMGR.XSL 1033

The simple answer is get Rufus... But also if you want the Progress Bar modify the BootMgr.exe.mui or the BootMgr.exe.efi.mui ... I have the files I can zip them up... alzio2020@gmail.com   ... I use the same shell all the time and just change the boot.wim file for the programs I want.

I have a Windows 10 USB Install from the Flash Drive ... Use WinToFlash

If you use Rufus and Don't Checkmark ... Use Rufus To Write MBR Bios ID
You Will Not Get a USB Prompt...   Not sure what you are looking for
but you can have it with the Prompt and without the Prompt using Rufus.

If I need to modify the Boot.wim file  I use GimageX

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and i used PS/2 keyboard and it worked (as you mentioned "I've read that this problem can be alleviated by using a PS/2 keyboard") .  For the people who face this problem, try using a PS/2 keyboard first.

Answer (score 0):

had the same issue, this helped:
BIOS settings > Integrated Peripherials > USB Keyboard Function  = Enabled
(was disabled)